# Mimic DTS Copy SQL Server Objects Task

Tags: sql-server, dts

I am in the process of migrating a web application database from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008.  Currently there is a DTS package that is used to deploy content changes from a staging database to the production database.

The DTS package is using a `Copy SQL Server Objects` task with the following options selected:  `Copy Data (Append Data)` and `Use Collation`.  The specific tables to copy are selected in the "Select Objects" dialog.

Because this is the only DTS package we have, it doesn't make much sense to learn and implement an SSIS solution, IMO, so I want to recreate the functioning of the DTS package using only T-SQL.

Writing the Insert and Select is not a problem.  What I need to know is how the "`Append Data`" option works.

Is it looking at each row in the source, finding matching rows in the destination, comparing and updating as necessary OR is is ignoring existing rows and simply appending new rows?

If it is indeed comparing and updating, is it safe to use the SQL Server `Checksum` function on the data as a method of comparison against the target or is there a better way?  Ideally, I'd like to avoid any schema changes.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this msdn article : [Migrating DTS Packages to Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768544%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

You might be able to migrate the single DTS package to SSIS package very easily using the tool noted in the article.